# JavaCC Beginner - How do I make the program only accept if there are no duplicates?

Tags: java, parsing, javacc

So I'm a beginner to JavaCC and I want to only accept this string if there are no duplicates of it. So if the input is below:

```
A B C
A' B' C'
A'' B'' C''
```

The parser will only accept it if `B != B' != B''

I feel like I'm missing something basic, and I can't find many easy to explain tutorials online for JavaCC. If someone could point me in the write direction that would be great.

Thanks in advance.`

EDIT: I should point out that currently my parser accepts the input above, regardless of duplicates.

Comment: That would normally fall into the category of semantic analysis, which would not normally be the responsibility of the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following.  In the parser class, declare a field

```
Set<String> seen = new HashSet<String>() ;
```

(This is assuming a nonstatic parser.  If the parser is static, the field must be static and must be reinitialized in the `reinit` function.)

Then in your productions, you can do something like this.

```
void start() : { Token t ;} {
    (   <A>
    t = <B> { if( seen.contains( t.image ) ) {
                  throw new ParserException( "Duplicate" ) ; }
              else { seen.add( t.image ) ; } }
        <C>
    )*
}
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble finding where to declare the Hashset. If i try and do it as you've done above it gets an error while compiling at the = part of the line

Comment: Sorry I've managed to figure it out with some fiddling. Thanks very much for your help in this. Do you know any sites that have an easy to understand tutorial that can help explain more about JavaCC. I feel like I'm mis-understanding a lot.

Comment: There is a (probably somewhat out of date) list of books and tutorials in the JavaCC FAQ. http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/   The JavaCC FAQ itself is also an excellent resource, I've been told, although, it is not revised as frequently as it should be.

Comment: With respect to the first comment: I will edit the answer.